# google sidebar & app script sending email composing subject and body

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, sidebar

I need help with setting up a google sheets sidebar to accept input for the subject and email body?

I have been able to get one to work but not both.  Code below....

```
<head>
    <title>Test Page</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
    Email Subject:<br>
        <input type="text" name="subject" size="36">
    Email Message:<br>
        <textarea name="body" rows="15" cols="37"style="Left"></textarea>
        <p>
        <input type="button" onClick="formSubmit()" value="Submit" />
        <input type="button" onClick="google.script.host.close()" value="Cancle" />

    </form>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function formSubmit() {
        google.script.run.sendEmail(document.forms[0],document.forms[1]);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use the values from textbox and textarea at `sendEmail()` of GAS side. If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? I think that there are several answers to your situation. So please think of this as one of them.

#### Modification points:

- There is no `</p>` for `<p>`.
- It used `this.parentNode` for retrieving values.

#### Modified script:

```
<head>
    <title>Test Page</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
    Email Subject:<br>
        <input type="text" name="subject" size="36">
    Email Message:<br>
        <textarea name="body" rows="15" cols="37"style="Left"></textarea>
        <!-- <p> -->
        <input type="button" onClick="formSubmit(this.parentNode)" value="Submit" />
        <input type="button" onClick="google.script.host.close()" value="Cancle" />
    </form>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function formSubmit(e) {
        google.script.run.sendEmail(e);
    }
</script>
```

#### Result:

`e` of `sendEmail(e)` at GAS is the following object.

```
{
  "subject": "sample subject",
  "body": "sample message"
}
```

If I misunderstand your question, please tell me. I would like to modify it.